# deleting dynamically allocated memory (MSVS 2012)

Tags: c++, memory-management

I've got a weird problem when deleting dynamically allocated memory. I am using MSVS 2012, and the error occurs

1) Only in release mode
2) Not during every run, although I always execute the same way and using the same data. The error occurs on average every 3-4th run.

Since it only occurs in release mode I put some cout commands in there to see where the program fails, and it always fails between tags #6 and #7, i.e. where I delete dynamically allocated memory which I have allocated a few steps earlier.

Here's the code:

```
long FOO::MainComputation(vector<double>InputArray, vector<double> & OutputArray)
{
    cout << "#1" << endl;
    // determine the size of the input array
    long NR_TOTINP = InputArray.size();
    // create dynamic array to hold the input array and copy values
    double * inparr = new double [NR_TOTINP];
    for (long i=0; i < NR_TOTINP; i++){inparr[i] = InputArray[i];}
    cout << "#2" << endl;
    // guess the size of the output array to allocate
    long NR_TOTOUT = InputArray.size() * 20 + 1;
    double * outarr = new double [NR_TOTOUT];
    cout << "#3" << endl;
    // call on the dll
    FOO_lfldld main_comp = (FOO_lfldld)GetProcAddress(hDLL,"Main_Comp");
    cout << "#4" << endl;
    long res = main_comp(NR_TOTINP,inparr,NR_TOTOUT,outarr);                                                    // todo: protect this with try... catch?
    // copy output parameters over
    cout << "#5" << endl;
    OutputArray.resize(NR_TOTOUT);
    for (long i=0; i < NR_TOTOUT; i++){OutputArray[i] = outarr[i];}
    cout << "#6" << endl;
    // delete dynamic arrays
    delete [] inparr;
    cout << "#7" << endl;
    delete [] outarr;
    cout << "#8" << endl;
    // done!
    return res;
}
```

I should note that the DLL called works fine with other code I have written (though in Python), so I do not suspect it to delete the memory on its own.

Any ideas?

Comment: What does `Main_Comp` on its arguments? Can you show its code?

Comment: Note: you can throw out your manual dynamic allocations by using `InputArray.data()` for the input parameter, and after sizing `OutputArray.resize(NR_TOTOUT)`, and use `OutputArray.data()` for the output parameter. All the rest of this jostling of new-ing, delete-ing, and copying can be thrown out.

Comment: Also, "I've got a weird problem ..." You then go on to describe *when* your "weird problem" happens, referring to it as "the error", but never say **what the error is**, so its not only weird, its apparently mysterious as well. Is it a process *crash* ? And are you aware you can build in full-release mode *with* debug symbols and, with debugger attached, debug your release bits similar to debug-bits?

Comment: `// guess the size of the output array to allocate` - What if you guessed wrong?

Comment: The obvious thing to do it to append a sentinel value to `outarr[]` and check if it's overwritten. If it is, you have your bug.

Comment: Thanks guys. WhozCraig suggestion to use OutputArray.data() appears to work fine, so I'll be using that.

Comment: The code was an attempt to mimic Visual Basic Code that the contractor who has written the DLL containing Main_Comp() has used. He's an old-style programmer hence, these oddities like sizing the output array in the way done.